# How to deploy Vue.js app on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, vue.js

I created a simple Vue.js application. Then I created a build for production using 
`npm run build` command which creates  `dist` folder in the project structure.

Then I use `gcloud app deploy` command to deploy it to Google App Engine, but then the deployment stops and gives error as:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.`

Can someone please tell me what is the proper way to deploy Vue.js application to Google App Engine?

Comment: Welcome to STackOverflow! You should do some research  on your own first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-app-engine%5d%20versions%20are%20limited%20to%2010000%20files

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried deploying your Vue.js app to Google App Engine using Cloud Build? I have had no problem deploying any Vue.js apps in this way. Try following this tutorial for [complete instructions.](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-deploy-vue-js-app-to-google-cloud-with-cloud-build-ad104bb1cf60)

Basically, you would have to include the following two files in your project root directory when deploying your Vue.js app to Google App Engine via Cloud Build:

1. App.yaml

   ```
   runtime: nodejs10
   handlers:
     # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
   - url: /(.*\..+)$ 
     static_files: dist/\1
     upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
     # catch all handler to index.html
   - url: /.*
     static_files: dist/index.html
     upload: dist/index.html
   ```

and

2. cloudbuild.yaml

   ```
   steps:
   - name: node:10.15.1
     entrypoint: npm
     args: ["install"]
   - name: node:10.15.1
     entrypoint: npm
     args: ["run", "build"]
   - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
     args: ["app", "deploy"]
   timeout: "1600s"
   ```

In the case you're not using cloud build you may just use the app.yaml above and reference the steps implied in the cloudbuild.yaml, which means:

1. run `npm install`
2. run `npm run build`
3. run `gcloud app deploy`

Answer (score 3):

You have too many files in the project.
In your `app.yaml` file, add the `skip_files` tag to it so the deployment does not include unnecessary files or folder in the upload. You can also mix with regex so for example:

```
skip_files:
- node_modules/
- .gitignore
- src/
- public/
- babel.config.js
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some Google Cloud Platform documentation that may be helpful to your issue, in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted) under the deployment section it's indicated that for every deployment you only can upload 10,000 files per version and each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. You're running into one of this two problems, I suggest to check this out on your app and try to deploy it again.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to waste $10 on namecheap for an SSL cert and hours of your time (like me) you probably want to add the `secure: always` option to each handler.

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  secure: always
```

like so! That's if you're using a custom domain though.

Comment: I got the money back lmao